# Type error when dispatch in React component + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, indexeddb

I'm getting a type error dispatch(**createNote(data)**) on handleSubmit
But if you close the error on the page and submit the data from the form, then the data is saved successfully in indexeddb

Error:

```
**Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'
(alias) createNote(data: Note): (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => void
import createNote**
```

At the same time, there are no errors in the slice itself.

I've tried changing Dispatch to any , no success

```
export const createNote = (data: Note) => (dispatch: any) => {
     console log(data);
     dispatch(createNoteReq());

     try {
         addNote(data);
         dispatch(noteCreate(data));
     } catch (error: any) {
         dispatch(notesReqFailed(error.message));
     }
};
```

```
export const createNote = (data: Note) => (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => {
     console log(data);
     dispatch(createNoteReq());

     try {
         addNote(data);
         dispatch(noteCreate(data));
     } catch (error: any) {
         dispatch(notesReqFailed(error.message));
     }
};
```

**UPD: Found a solution on the surface**

[Need to use useAppDispatch vs useDispatch and useAppSelector vs useSelector](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using redux's dispatch you should export the type from redux store and import it into your component

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer,
    users: usersReducer
  }
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch
export const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```